# Print collection in a list of a collection in mongodb in golang

Tags: mongodb, go

To print a collection from mongodb the following is my code in python:

```
print(list(MongoClient(***).get_database("ChatDB").get_collection("room_members".find({'_id.username': username})))
```

I am learning Go and I am trying to translate the aforementioned code into golang.

My code is as follows:

```
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), options.Client().ApplyURI("*****"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    likes_collection := client.Database("ChatDB").Collection("likes")
    cur, err := likes_collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.D{{}})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer cur.Close(context.Background())
    fmt.Println(cur)
```

However, I get some hex value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongo in go lang different api than mongo.

Find returns cursor not collection.

You should changed your code to :

```
var items []Items 
cur, err := likes_collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.D{{}})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
cur.All(context.Background(),&items)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("***"))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
var likes []bson.M
likes_collection := client.Database("ChatDB").Collection("likes")

defer client.Disconnect(ctx)

cursor, err := likes_collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.D{{}})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err = cursor.All(ctx, &likes); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(likes)
```